# C# serialPort speed

Tags: c#, .net, performance, serial-port

I am developing some monitoring tool for some kind of protocol based on serial communication.

Serial BaudRate=187,5kb
I use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class.

This protocol has 4 kinds of frames. They have 1Byte,3Bytes,6Bytes, 10-255Bytes. **I can work with them but I receive them too late to respond**.

For the beginning I receive first packed after ex. 96ms (too late), and it contains about 1000B. This means 20-50 frames (too much, too late).
Later its work more stable, 3-10Bytes but it is still too late because it contains 1-2 frames. Of Course 1 frame is OK, but 2 is too late.

Can you point me how can I deal with it more reliable? I know it is possible.

Revision1:

I tried straight way:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
       if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;
       this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(this.DataReceived));
}
```

And Backgroud worker:
And ... new Tread(Read)
and... always the same. Too late, too slow.
Do I have to go back to WinApi and import some kernel32.dll functions?

Revision 2:
this is the part of code use in the Treading way:

```
int c = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
byte[] b = new byte[c];
serialPort1.Read(b, 0, c);
```

I guess it is some problem with stream use inside SerialPort class. Or some synchronization problem.

Revision 3:
I do not use both at once!! I just tried different ways.

Regards
MarekK

Comment: Without some kind of code and some sort of information very few people will be able to help you. How do you read from the port?

Comment: Generaly the code works and is quite big. It looks that some part of code is waiting for something. I do not know witch one.

Comment: **I tried to use BaseStream which is SerialPort sub class.
I got the same result. BUT !!!!!!
I started to look for PCIe card for my laptop and I've found that converters based on USB even in PCI expresscard does not provide good communication level because of USB stack. Where as I think data stream is waiting for USB procedures. I can imagine that this makes the most difficulties. I'm going to buy PCIe 232 card.**

Comment: Maybe this gives you a clue, why it is too slow:
[Performance Of System.IO.Ports Versus Unmanaged Serial Port Code](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PerformanceOfSystemIOPortsVersusUnmanagedSerialPortCode.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read this [first](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NET_20_SerialPort.aspx), as this bug has to do with DataReceived Event which does not fire at times, and it is still not fixed in Framework 3.0/3.5. Also, you should read something [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/aa5280a4-b3aa-4e96-98d0-4e587892a68e/) about this poster who reported the problem to Microsoft when he had issues using it, under VS2008/NET 3.5...I cannot say if that is true or not...but is something worth keeping in mind about...and Microsoft did have a certain amount of difficulty with the .NET version which was introduced into .NET version 2.

At the time, I was using .NET 1.1, I came across suggestions to use the version that came with VB6's ActiveX control, which according to [source](http://www.codeworks.it/net/VBNetRs232.htm)s on the internet, that it was the best serial comms control!!!

You might be better to investigate using a third party code to handle the serial communications, usually, the ones written outside of the managed world, i.e. unmanaged using lots of p/invokes.

I have tried using John Hind's version found in the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301786.aspx), which I did find very off-putting as there was no way to do it asynchronously, plus it was a horrible coding experience..

I did end up using one supplied by [Franson](http://franson.com/serialtools/) which produced better results than Hind's code.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.