# bug in serial port communication

Tags: c#, serial-port

I might just have the weirdest bug you've heard today.

I have this one (very long) method inside a thread, which sends formatted data to a RS232 Led Display.

It should display something like this

```
TITLE
SUBTITLE 1
ELEMENT 1
ELEMENT 2
SUBTITLE 2
ELEMENT 1
ELEMENT 2
ELEMENT 3
```

well, each one on it's own message.

I'm calling Thread.Sleep(N) after each one of the messages (so each message is displayed N time).

- N being the number of seconds

Ok, everything is fine until now. The thing is that if `(10 <= N <= 20)` I get the following output:

```
TITLE
TITLE
TITLE
TITLE
TITLE
TITLE
TITLE
TITLE
```

I can hear the *beep* when I send the message. I even installed a serial port monitor, to check if the information I was sending was the same.

So just to summarize:

Writing on Serial Port works after sleeping the thread for n <= 9 or n >= 20. Anything in between will produce an erroneous output, like if the output was cached or something

What can this be?

**Update**

- Ok, I know System.Threading.Sleep takes miliseconds as arguments. just multiply the number by 1000.
- Whenever the led display receives a new well formatted message, it beeps. I should have clarified that.

Here is a snippet (this sends the first title)

```
            using (var ld = new LedScreen(COM))
            {                    
                ld.AddEffect(LedScreen.Effects.Snow);
                ld.AddText(LedScreen.Colors.Red, titulos[ThreadControl.Fase]);
                ld.AddEffect(LedScreen.Effects.DSnow);
                ld.Write();
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(titulos[ThreadControl.Fase]);
            //esperamos N tiempo (titulo)
            Thread.Sleep(TiempoTitulo);
```

I wrote the LedScreen class. The write method is this one:

```
    public void Write()
    {
        //caracteres de terminacion
        buffer.AddRange(new byte[] { 0xBF, 0xB1 });
        try
        {
            if (!sp.IsOpen) sp.Open();
            sp.Write(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.Count);
        }
        finally
        {
            sp.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Update 2**

I finally got it to work (ugly fix, but meh.)

Before each write to the serial port, I send a "blank" message with no delay. That clears the screen, before sending the actual message. hooray! and it works for whatever amount of seconds I sleep the thread

Comment: Can you post a code snippet surrounding the sleep and sending of the serial message?

Comment: There is a known issue with the serial comms component since .NET 2.0...it was hoped that it would be addressed in .NET 3.5 but nope...

Comment: There's nothing in your question that would allow anybody to diagnose what the problem might be.  Find out what "beep" means.  SerialPort doesn't beep.

Comment: @nobugz: maybe he meant that the LED beeps when the data transmission of the instructions occur...

Comment: @tommieb75:  care to provide a link to this known issue?  Without seeing the code there's no way to know whether this known issue is at fault or not.

Comment: @tommieb75, do you have a url/reference?

Comment: @tommie: LEDs usually blink instead of beep.  Maybe he's accidentally zapping the cat :)

Comment: @nobugz: lol depends on what the cat is doing to the serial port or the serial port doing to the cat.... :)

Comment: @sam: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NET_20_SerialPort.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/SerialPortDotNet.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311459/c-serialport-speed/2035802#2035802

Comment: @tommieb75, Those references are related to data received.  The OP is asking about sending data.  Doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: @sam: ahhh but did you read the links in my answer to the stackoverflow question that I linked previously....

Comment: @tommieb75, I read all your links.  I see bugs, but nothing on point with the original question here.  Can you be more precise?

Comment: One issue might be here that Sleep(N) sleeps N milliseconds, not N seconds. With a resolution of approx 20 ms.

Comment: @sam: I do reckon that the serial-port has a timing issue which is not resolved...hence the op's question...there is obviously a timing issue that he is experiencing, especially if it's a component that is used at design time, ie. dragged from the toolbox onto a form...taking into consideration of threading...tbh, serial port is a quirky thing. the best serial port activex by far was VB6's mscomm.ocx which performs better than the built in serialport...this may be subjective opinion...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, can you please clarify the thread's sleep time?  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() takes a milliseconds argument, not a 'seconds' argument.

Next, do you know that the serial port write() succeeds?  (A hard coded delay of 10-20 msecs is not necessarily always long enough.)

To prevent overrunning, I do something like:

```
    public bool Send(byte[] bytes)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log or note the error: can be TimeoutException or InvalidOperationException, etc
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that might affect your situation, not the least of which is the already-mentioned "you're talking seconds, but Sleep() takes a milliseconds argument, not seconds" issue.

You also need to look at length of time between characters sent.  Flow control too.  Serial port parameters (baud rate, etc...). And you need to know what the tolerance of your device is.  Lost data on a serial transmission usually means you are overloading the device on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the device's algorithm for detecting end-of-message (EOM)?  It could be that the device uses an intra-character timeout.  That could explain why it works with N > 20, if no new characters showed up in the buffer in that time then the device might decide that the message was terminated and display the buffer.  If you are putting ASCII code 10 at the end of the messages, it may be deciding that the rest of the message scrolls off the end of the one-line display and not show it.

That wouldn't explain the N < 9 working, though.  Perhaps if data arrives without any delay at all the device interprets it as a script to display serially?  The indication that that is the case is if the speed at which messages display doesn't vary for N = 0 to 9, but it does vary for all N's > 20.  If N is in milliseconds you may not be able to confirm this.